# Minimum good answer to pass Magento certification

Tags: frontend, certification

I will soon attend the Front-End Magento certification, and I can't find anywhere what's the miminum good answers ratio to pass the certification. A colleague told me it's maybe around 70% good answers but he's not sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to Magento programming or usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento Certified Front End Developer exam passing score: 44 or higher

For more details [click here](http://magento.com/training/certification-faq)

Comment: Is it minimum 44% good answers to pass it ?

Comment: no its a value for points or score.every question has a different value of score. if you answered the question correct you will get the points, otherwise not.

Comment: Magento Front End Developer Certification exam consists of 81 questions. 16 of them are unmarked - therefore only 65 are marked and count towards your percentage. You will not know which of the questions are unmarked. If you have still confusion then contact with certification@magento.com .

Comment: • Magento Certified Developer exam: 37 or higher
• Magento Certified Developer Plus exam: For sections 11 & 12 combined a score of 7 or higher AND meet the overall passing score of 48 or higher
• Magento Certified Front End Developer exam: 44 or higher
• Magento Certified Solution Specialist exam: 39 or higher